# RegEx .NET match string C where string A OR B are not present

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I thought I knew a thing or two... then I met RegEx.
So what I am trying to do is a multistring negative look-ahead? Is that a thing?
Basically I want to find when a 3rd string exists BUT two precursory strings do NOT.

```
(?i:<!((yellow thing)\s(w+\s+){0,20}(blue thing))\s(\w+\s+){0,100}(green thing))
```

Target String:

- Here we have a yellow thing. Here we have a blue thing. Clearly the green thing is best though. (Should NOT match)
- You wanna buy some death sticks? I have a green thing. (MATCH)
- We are on a yellow thing submarine? Look at that green thing over there! (MATCH)

Comment: You ruined the lookbehind and turned it into an option group with inline modifier. Try `(?<!yellow thing\W*(\w+\W+){0,20}\W*blue thing\W*(\w+\W+){0,100})green thing`.  Word boundaries can be added around the "thing"s to match whole words only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?:(?!\byellow thing\b.*?\bblue thing\b).)*\bgreen thing\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dL0uZ1/2

Explanation:

- look for the "green thing" (`\b`'s around it mark word boundaries)
- but only if it is not preceded by the two other strings as seen from the beginning of the text line hence `^` followed by the "string not containing a pattern" pattern (see [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) for more details on it).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as an attempt to only match `c` *inside* the string, not the whole string, using the negative lookbehind of infinite width.

You spoiled the lookbehind structure by inserting `i:` right after `?`, and you missed the fact that there can be non-word characters in-between "words".

Thus, you need

```
(?<!yellow thing\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,20}\W*blue thing\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,100})green thing
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!yellow%20thing%5CW*(%5Cw%2B%5CW%2B)%7B0%2C20%7D%5CW*blue%20thing%5CW*(%5Cw%2B%5CW%2B)%7B0%2C100%7D)green%20thing&i=Here%20we%20have%20a%20yellow%20thing.%20Here%20we%20have%20a%20blue%20thing.%20Clearly%20the%20green%20thing%20is%20best%20though.%20%20(NO%20MATCH%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200)%0D%0AYou%20wanna%20buy%20some%20death%20sticks%3F%20I%20have%20a%20green%20thing.%20(MATCH%20%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200)%0D%0AWe%20are%20on%20a%20yellow%20thing%20submarine%3F%20Look%20at%20that%20green%20thing%20over%20there!%20(MATCH%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%200)) where I added numbers to emulate the number of optional words in-between matches.

**NOTE**: You may add word boundaries around `thing`s to match them as whole words only - that depends on your requirements.

Also, you may turn all capturing groups `(\w+\W+)` into non-capturing to keep these group stacks free (no need to keep track of what these groups capture, right?) If you need to capture them, keep capture groups intact.

Results:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Very nice. I see the error of my ways. Thank you sir.
Also I used the ?i because it ignores case.
    (?i:(?<!yellow thing\W*(\w+\W+){0,20}\W*blue thing\W*(\w+\W+){0,100})green thing)

Comment: You may just use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag when using the pattern with `Regex` methods.